# combine multiple textures into one without baking

Tags: texturing

I have a computer generated architecture model with around 110 bmp texture files. These texture files are all photoreal. I want to combine the texture files into one file without the remapping process.

So far I know there is a texture atlas addon, but this only allows plain colour texture files. There is also cycles baking, but the result is horrible, the architecture's appearance looks like a mess. Are there anymore ways that can combine the texture files into one file?

My Blender version is 2.8.